# Compute recursively the largest substring which starts and ends with sub and return its length

Tags: java, string, recursion, substring

The task is: Given a string and a non-empty substring sub, compute recursively the largest substring which starts and ends with sub and return its length.

Examples:

```
strDist("catcowcat", "cat") → 9
strDist("catcowcat", "cow") → 3
strDist("cccatcowcatxx", "cat") → 9
```

Can you please look at my code and tell me what is the problem with it?

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub)
{

  if(str.length()<sub.length())
  return 0;
  if(str.length()==sub.length()&&str.equals(sub))
  return str.length();

  if(str.length()<2)
  {
    if(str.contains(sub))
    {

      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  }

  if (str.length()==2)
 {
   if (sub.length()==2 && str.equals(sub))
   return 2;
   if (str.contains(sub))
   return 1;
   return 0;
 }

if(str.length()>2)
{
   if(str.startsWith(sub)&&str.endsWith(sub))
   {
     return str.length();
   }
   if(str.substring(0,sub.length()).equals(sub))
   {
    strDist(str.substring(0,str.length()-2),sub);
   }
   if(str.substring(str.length()-sub.length(),str.length()-1).equals(sub))
   strDist(str.substring(1,str.length()-1),sub);
}
  return strDist(str.substring(1,str.length()-1),sub);



}
```

it doesn't work for the case  `strDist("hiHellohihihi", "hih")` → 5
and returns zero.

Comment: You should describe your algorithm first! how does it works in your examples? you can use pseudo-code.

Comment: Hint: such code is **perfect** for unit testing. You should write tests that have for known input that check for the expected results. That would allow you to assess your code much better than just throwing it in front of other people to digest it, as you see: your code is kinda hard to read. Such lengthy if chains; with complicated conditions, and that many method calls ... not ideally easy to digest ... I also find your example **unclear**. There is **no** substring in there that starts and ends with cow, so can the length be 3 then? Shouldnt it be 0?

Comment: Without going deep in your code, the last two `if` conditions are calling `strDist` recursively but are ignoring the return value. You probably should review that, seems like an error.

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion for such a relatively simple task? I cannot see it makes sense to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to answer your question, I found a number of issues in your code. My corrected version follows, with comments about the changes I did.

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {

    if (str.length() < sub.length())
        return 0;
    // simplified condition
    if (str.equals(sub))
        return str.length();

    if (str.length() < 2) {
        if (str.contains(sub)) {
            // corrected (if str and sub are both empty strings, you don’t want to return 1)
            return str.length();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // deleted str.length() == 2 case that didn’t work correctly

    if (str.startsWith(sub) && str.endsWith(sub)) {
        return str.length();
    }
    if (str.startsWith(sub)) { // simplified
        // subtracting only 1 and added return statement
        return strDist(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), sub);
    }
    // changed completely -- didn’t understand; added return statement, I believe this solved your test case
    if (str.endsWith(sub))
        return strDist(str.substring(1), sub);
    return strDist(str.substring(1, str.length() - 1), sub);

}
```

Now if I do:

```
    System.out.println(strDist("catcowcat", "cat"));
    System.out.println(strDist("catcowcat", "cow"));
    System.out.println(strDist("cccatcowcatxx", "cat"));
    System.out.println(strDist("hiHellohihihi", "hih"));
```

I get:

```
9
3
9
5
```

Second, as I said in a comment, I see no point in using recursion here (except perhaps for the exercise). The following version of your method doesn’t, it’s much simpler and it works the same:

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
    int firstOccurrence = str.indexOf(sub);
    if (firstOccurrence == -1) { // sub not in str
        return 0;
    }
    int lastOccurrence = str.lastIndexOf(sub);
    return lastOccurrence - firstOccurrence + sub.length();
}
```

Finally, and this may or may not be helpful, a recursive version needs not be as complicated as yours:

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
    if (sub.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("sub mustn’t be empty");
    }
    if (str.length() <= sub.length()) {
        if (str.equals(sub)) {
            return str.length();
        } else { // sub cannot be in str
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (str.startsWith(sub)) {
        if (str.endsWith(sub)) {
            return str.length();
        } else {
            return strDist(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), sub);
        }
    } else {
        return strDist(str.substring(1), sub);
    }
}
```

It’s fine to get something to work first if you can, even if it’s not the most simple and elegant solution. When either it works or it doesn’t, is a good time to think of ways to simplify. It will make it easier to nail down the bug(s) and also ease maintenance later. Special cases, like length 1 and length 2, are often a good candidate for simplification: see if the general code already caters for them or can easily be made to.

Comment: Oops, I missed the part about the two string being supposed to be non-empty. Should have added parameter validation. :-)

Comment: thank you very much! the case what I was asking for really works now, but I have a problem with a case strDist("hiHellohihihi", "ll").

Comment: the task was to do it with recursion, and I just want to understand my mistakes.

Comment: Glad it helped. The case `strDist("hiHellohihihi", "ll")` should yield 2, do we agree? When I run my corrected version of your method, it does yield 2.

Comment: @Alex, I like that attitude — trying to understand your mistakes.

Comment: I don't think it will work with catwomencatmancat -> the answer should be women or 5.

Comment: @Learner On my computer `strDist("catwomencatmancat", "women")` yields 5 no matter if I call the recursive or the non-recursive method. Note that the method takes two arguments.

Comment: if (str.startsWith(sub)) {
        if (str.endsWith(sub)) {
            return str.length();
        } This section ends up returning womencatman length

Comment: The sub in my example is cat

Comment: The entire string starts and ends with `cat`, so in that case the length of the entire string (17) should be returned. All three versions of my method do that. They work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

this is my way of solving it, it is kinda similar but i find it simpler (hope it helps)  :

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) { 

  if(str.length() < sub.length())
    return 0;

  if(!str.contains(sub))return 0;

  if(str.startsWith(sub)&& str.endsWith(sub))
    return str.length();

  if(str.startsWith(sub) )
    return  strDist(str.substring(0,str.length()-1),sub);

  if(str.endsWith(sub)) 
    return strDist(str.substring(1,str.length()),sub);

  else return strDist(str.substring(1,str.length()-1),sub);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is hard to follow. It would be more appropriate to describe the algorithm rather to provide the implementation.

Based on the description, below is my implementation. I think it is concise and easy to understand.

```
class Example {

    private static int indexOf(String str, int idx, String sub, int res) {

        if (str.length() < sub.length()) return res;

        int tmp = str.indexOf(sub, idx);

        if (tmp < 0) return res;

        return Math.max(tmp, indexOf(str, tmp + 1, sub, res));

    }

    public static int strDist(String str, String sub) {

        if (str.length() < sub.length()) return 0;


        int from = str.indexOf(sub);
        int to = indexOf(str, from + 1, sub, from);


        return to - from + sub.length();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(strDist("catcowcat", "cat"));
        System.out.println(strDist("catcowcat", "cow"));
        System.out.println(strDist("cccatcowcatxx", "cat"));
        System.out.println(strDist("hiHellohihihi", "hih"));
    }
}
```

Result:

```
9
3
9
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, others have already answered with the recursive code, I have included an O(n) solution using KMP algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> failureFunction(string a){
    int n= a.length();
    vector<int> f(n+1);
    f[0]=f[1]=0;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        int j = f[i-1];
        while(1){
            if( a[j]== a[i-1]){
                f[i]= j+1;
                break;
            }
            else if (j==0){
                f[i]= 0;
                break;
            }
            else j = f[j];
        }
    }
    return f;
}
int strDist(string str , string sub ){
    int n= sub.length();
    int m= str.length();
    vector<int> f = failureFunction(sub);
    vector<int> ff(m+1);

    ff[0]= (str[0]==sub[0]) ? 1 : 0;
    for(int i=1;i<m;i++){
        int j = ff[i-1];
        if(j==n)
            j=f[j];
        while(1){
            if(  sub[j] == str[i] ){
                ff[i]= j+1;
                break;
            }
            else if(j==0){
                ff[i]= 0;
                break;
            }
            else j= f[j];
        }
    }
    int first_occ = -1, last_occ= -1;
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        if( ff[i]==n ){
            if( first_occ == -1 ){
                first_occ = i-n+1;
            }
            last_occ = i;
        }
    }
    if ( first_occ == -1 )
        return 0;
    else    
    return last_occ - first_occ + 1;
}   
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    cout<<strDist("catcowcat", "cat")<<endl;
    cout<<strDist("hiHellohihihi", "hih")<<endl;
    cout<<strDist("catcowcat", "cow")<<endl;
    cout<<strDist("cccatcowcatxx", "cat")<<endl;
    cout<<strDist("xx","y");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++. A chance for the rest of to brush up …

Answer (score 0):

A small solution with explanation

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {
  // base case
  if(str.length() < sub.length() || !str.contains(sub)) return 0;

  // success case      
  if(str.startsWith(sub) && str.endsWith(sub)) {
    return str.length(); 
  }

  // cleaning the end of the string to be able to find the success case if exists
  if(str.startsWith(sub)) {
    return strDist(str.substring(0, str.length() - 1), sub);
  }

  // cleaning the begin of the string to be able to find the success case if exists
  return strDist(str.substring(1), sub);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more raw solution.

```
public int strDist(String str, String sub) {

  //first base case to check if the string doesnt have the substring
  if(str.length() < sub.length()) return 0;

  //check if the string starts with the substring
  if(str.substring(0,sub.length()).equals(sub)){

    //check if the string ends with the substring, if so return the length of the string
    if(str.substring(str.length() - sub.length(),str.length()).equals(sub)){
      return str.length();
    }

    //if the above condition fails, shave the last charater of the string and recurse
    return strDist(str.substring(0,str.length()-1),sub);
  }

  //keep searching for the substring to appear in the string
  return strDist(str.substring(1),sub);
}
```